# Encrypting a string over network, c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a client-server program that send and receive a string (its a simple chat app over LAN).

The program works fine, but i need to encrypt it, and that's the problem, when i use encryption it seems that it close the connection after each time sending the data,and i need to re-run it in order to receive further messages (which I can't because its chatting and should be continually)

***By the way I don't mind even if its a weak encryption as long as its not plain-text is fine.***

Here is one side of my program (server):

```
public static void Main()
   {
      string data;
      IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9999);

      Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

      socket.Bind(ip);
      socket.Listen(10);

      Socket client = socket.Accept();
      IPEndPoint newclient = (IPEndPoint)client.RemoteEndPoint;
      Console.WriteLine("Connected with {0} at port {1}",newclient.Address, newclient.Port);

      NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(client);
      StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ns);
      StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ns);

      string welcome = "Welcome";
      sw.WriteLine(welcome);
      sw.Flush();

      while(true)
      {
         data = sr.ReadLine();
         Console.WriteLine(data);
         sw.WriteLine(data);
         sw.Flush();
      }
      Console.WriteLine("Disconnected from {0}", newclient.Address);
      sw.Close();
      sr.Close();
      ns.Close(); 
   }
```

Here is the example of the code, that I've tried to use for encrypting:(server)
  IPAddress IP2 = IPAddress.Parse(IP);
                TcpListener TCPListen = new TcpListener(IP2, port);

```
                TCPListen.Start();

            TcpClient TCP = TCPListen.AcceptTcpClient();


            NetworkStream NetStream = TCP.GetStream();




            RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();


            byte[] Key = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16 };
            byte[] IV = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16 };




            CryptoStream CryptStream = new CryptoStream(NetStream,
               RMCrypto.CreateDecryptor(Key, IV),
               CryptoStreamMode.Read);

            StreamReader SReader = new StreamReader(CryptStream);




            message = SReader.ReadToEnd();

            textBox3.Clear();

            textBox3.Text = message;

            CryptStream.Flush();

            SReader.Close();







            NetStream.Flush();

            NetStream.Close();

            TCPListen.Stop();
            TCP.Close();
```

I've tried to only flush the netstream and cryptstream so can leave the connection open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered simply using [SSL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx) for your socket communication? (Specifying SslProtocols.Tls).

SSL Socket support has been in .NET since C# 2.0.

---

If you want to keep your code mostly the same as you have now simply use an encoding with your encrypted binary data and that'll probably fix your problem.  For example `Convert.ToBase64String` before sending.

Comment: Sorry if I ask a so dumb question,I'm a beginner,Let me see if I got it right,you mean instead of using any encryption, change the encoding when its over the net and on the other side again converting to 32 base right?

Comment: @user363295: There are no dumb questions.  If you really don't care about security I guess you can simply base64 encode the string before you send and base64 decode right after you receive.  This is not a replacement for encryption though it simply gets rid of clear text.  A person could figure it out on paper if they wanted to even.

Comment: It is completely different between encoding a text and encrypting a text. Encoding a text DOES NOTHING to make it unaccessible, it just changed the way to save the text, the text will be VISIBLE to a hacker (if it's what you're concern, someone who can tap your LAN can easily read Base64 string). Encryption is the only way to keep your communication safe. NOT ENCODING. no offence to answer but I think the person who's asking question need to know this.

Comment: VOX: Agree and it was explicitly mentioned by me above.   The answer that was accepted said to base64 the encrypted data for safe transmission.  The comment that I left above explicitly stated that it is not encryption and someone can even decode it with paper and pencil.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at TLS.

It's not really complicated and it's as safe as it gets.

A tutorial for .NET is available here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/sslclasses.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Well reading that code it should *never* stop writing data as it has a `while(true)` without any exit condition.

Under what circumstances does the server close the connection? It it possible that it looks for a particular character and your encrypted output includes this character?

Comment: It's a chat it reads from one side and write to netstream from other side,works until u close the program(the loop never ends).

Comment: So what is the point of the `Disconnected from {}` code as it will never get there? It will also never properly close the connection resources. Again, when does the server close the connection? Where is your example with encryption that causes the problem?

Comment: There is no enough space here to put the code,so I will edit the question.

Comment: And yeah you are right, it never gets to that    Console.WriteLine("Disconnected from {0}", newclient.Address);
so it server never close the connection.

Comment: In your example you are calling `TCPListen.Stop();` and  `TCP.Close();`

Comment: I know that they close the connection. but I've tried all the possible situations, removing this too from one side or both side will cause the program don't sending the data.